# I need a regular express for notepad++ to remove new line and empty spaces

Tags: php, mysql, regex, replace, notepad++

here is a sample text:

```
a:7:{
        i:0;
        i:9;
    }
```

I want all the new lines and empty spaces to be removed so it would look like this:

```
a:7:{i:0;i:9;}
```

So I'm using notepad++ for editing and im wondering how to the above with the find and replace feature.

Comment: Just use `[\r\n\s]`... You could have googled this

Comment: ok but how do i put that into notepad++ find/replace function?

Comment: In the Replace Tab you insert it in "Find what" and replace it with nothing. Check Wrap around and Regular expression and click Replace All

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+H to open the replace window.

In Search mode select Regular expression and check the "matches newline" checkbox.

In the "Find what" type - \s

Leave the "Replace with" field empty

Select the "Wrap around" checkbox and hit "Replace All"

EDIT: Adding screenshot for reference:

[image]

Comment: I typed \s in the find box and everything else you said and still did not work.

Comment: Seems to work for me. I am using v6.5.3. How about you?

Comment: I have added a screenshot.